# Две буквы "н" в слове "склонённые"

Tags: орфография

Почему слово "склонённые" пишется с двумя "н"?

Answer (score 3):

От глаголов образуются **причастия** (НН) и **отглагольные прилагательные** (Н и НН). Чтобы не проводить сложный грамматический анализ при выборе Н и НН, пользуются простым **формальным правилом 4-х признаков**:

**Две буквы НН** пишутся в полных отглагольных прилагательных и причастиях  при наличии следующих 4-х признаков:

А) ПРИСТАВКИ: покрашенный,  побелённый раскрашенный, раскалённый поджаренный, названный;

Б)  ЗАВИСИМОГО СЛОВА (крашенный масляной краской забор,  жаренное в духовке мясо);

В) ГЛАГОЛЬНОГО СУФФИКСА ОВА/ЕВА (маринованный, дрессированный бракованный, дарованный гарантированный);

Г) ПРИ ОБРАЗОВАНИИ ОТ ГЛАГОЛА СОВЕРШЕННОГО ВИДА: (брошенный, обиженный, купленный сочинённый).

**Одна буква Н** пишется в полных отглагольных прилагательных при отсутствии указанных 4-х признаков.

Правило имеет **исключения (как и все формальные правила):**

1)Две буквы НН при отсутствии 4-х признаков пишется в прилагательных со значением  общего отношения к действию, а не результата действия (эти прилагательные  не составляют пару прилагательное-причастие, как указывается в правилах 4-х признаков): **нежданный, негаданный,  неслыханный, невиданный,  нечаянный, отчаянный, медленный,  священный,  деланный, беспрестанный**

2) Одна буква Н: названый  брат, посажёный отец, смышлёный ребёнок.

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

Склоненный - приставка С, сов. вид глагола "склонить", поэтому пишется две буквы НН.

Answer (score 1):

*Склоненный* — это причастие, образованное от глагола совершенного вида *склонить*.

Если причастие образовано от глагола совершенного вида (как в данном случае), то в слове пишется двойная согласная Н.

Викисловарь иногда помогает: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Страдательные причастия прошедшего времени всегда образуются от глаголов совершенного вида, также в причастиях (в полной форме) всегда пишутся две буквы НН.

Comment: Vera, вряд ли этому пользователю нужна настолько подробная информация. Я по-простому оформил свой ответ.

Comment: Я поняла вашу мысль, и, изложенная по-простому,  она, безусловно, верна. Но всё-таки логика письма нарушена союзом "если". Достаточно было написать " так как слово образовано от глагола совершенного вида", и тогда бы не было вопросов.